# php, loop through each child page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a total newb with php, so forgive me if this is a dumb question.

**What i want is: grab current page id (which is a parent page), find al child pages of that specific parent page
and output permalink and title for each of those child pages**

The following code works, except it is for a category, not a parent page (and i have to manually add the category page id)

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="maddos-category-container">
        <div class="maddos-category-header">
            <h3 class="maddos-category-header-title">
                <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( "17" );?>">
                    <?php echo get_cat_name(17);?>
                </a>
            </h3>
        </div>

       <div class="maddos-category-wrapper">
           <ol>
               <?php
                   $args = array('category' => 17, 'post_type' =>  'post',  'numberposts' => -1); 
                   $postslist = get_posts($args);    

                   foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
               ?>  
                       <li>
                           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                               <?php the_title(); ?>
                           </a>
                       </li> 
                   <?php endforeach; ?>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </ol>
```

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me with this (i don't really know php, but i do need to solve this issue)

edit:
This is what i got (thnx for the wordpress comments) (and this works)

what would be the best way to exclude page 8020 and 9021 for example?

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
 );


$parent = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>





<?php the_permalink(); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>



    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: where is parent id, meaning it is in URL section or your getting from somewhere else?

Comment: This looks like WordPress, so you should use WP functionality as far as possible. Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/29196576/1427878, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/299138 or https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-a-list-of-child-pages-for-a-parent-page-in-wordpress/ for initial inspiration maybe.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113914/list-child-pages-of-a-specific-page

Comment: @EvilsEmpire This is Wordpress and [`get_the_ID()` is documented in the codex as usual](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/).

Comment: @javanewby When working with Wordpress, keep in mind that Wordpress offers a utility function for nearly everything. [The Wordpress Codex is your friend.](https://codex.wordpress.org/) And if there is no core-function to help you out, [have a look at the plugin repository too](https://wordpress.org/plugins/).

Comment: Thnx guys, with the comments i got a long way, i got my solution (but ran in 1 more problem XD)  what would be the bext way to exclude 2 page ids from the loop?